# Ribbon.InvalidateControl not working on PPT 2010

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ribbonx

I have a an add-in within the Insert Ribbon of PPT 2010. Basically what I want to do is to make a selection in a combo box, then run a macro, then set the combo box to blank. Unfortunately I´v been unable to clear the selection.

I have searched all over the web with various methods and nothing helps. Hope someone can help.

My XML

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="VirtusInitialize">
<ribbon>
<tabs>
<tab idMso="TabInsert">
<group id="CustomGroup1" label="Sticker">
<box id="box1" boxStyle="horizontal">
    <comboBox id="ddlItem" label="STICKER 1" onChange="Sticker1">
      <item id="BU" label="BACK UP" />
    </comboBox>
</box>
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

VBA code:

```
Private MyRibbonV As IRibbonUI


Public Sub VirtusInitialize(ByVal ribbon As Office.IRibbonUI)
  Set MyRibbonV = ribbon
End Sub

Sub Sticker1(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, text As String)
 'do stuff
  MyRibbonV.InvalidateControl ("ddlItem")
End Sub
```

Comment: Try invalidating the entire ribbon like `MyRibbonV.InvalidateRibbon`

Comment: When I try this approach I get the following error: Object doesn't suppor property or method

Comment: Oops! The method call should be just `MyRibbonV.Invalidate`. Interface documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa433869(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternatively use a Dropdown control instead of combobox**

I found some information here, at least enough to get started...

http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html

Use XML like:

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="VirtusInitialize">
<ribbon>
<tabs>
<tab idMso="TabInsert">
<group id="CustomGroup1" label="Sticker">
<box id="box1" boxStyle="horizontal">
    <dropDown id="ddlItem" label="STICKER 1" 
                      getItemCount="GetItemCount"
                      getItemLabel="GetItemLabel"
                      getSelectedItemIndex="GetSelectedItemIndex"
                      onAction="Sticker1" >
    </dropDown>
</box>
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

And VBA callbacks:

```vb
Private MyRibbonV As IRibbonUI

Public Sub VirtusInitialize(ByVal ribbon As Office.IRibbonUI)
  Set MyRibbonV = ribbon
End Sub

Sub Sticker1(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, id As String, index As Integer)
 'do stuff
  Select Case index
      Case 0

      Case 1
      'do stuff
      Case 2
      'do stuff
  End Select

  MyRibbonV.Invalidate
End Sub


'Callback for ddlItem getItemCount
Sub GetItemCount(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
'puts 3 items in the dropdown and triggers the GetItemLabel
returnedVal = 3
End Sub

'Callback for ddlItem getItemLabel
Sub GetItemLabel(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef returnedVal)
Dim str$
Select Case index
    Case 0
        str = " "
    Case 1
        str = "BACK UP"
    Case 2
        str = "GO FORWARD"
End Select
returnedVal = str
End Sub

'Callback for ddlItem getSelectedItemIndex
Sub GetSelectedItemIndex(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
'not used
End Sub
'Callback for ddlItem getText
Sub GetText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
'not used
End Sub
'Callback for ddlItem getItemID
Sub GetItemID(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef id)
'not used...
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried using this approach (which is very similar to mine), however still not working. VBA reads Rib.Invalidate but nothing happens, no error, no invalidation, nothing at all...

Comment: ok. i've never used a combobox on the ribbon ui before. where do you populate it's listitems?

Comment: on a XML file directly, not in the macro itself

Comment: I don't grok that. Can you describe in more detail? The ComboBox is in the ribbon/context menu, but you're "populating list items in to an XML file directly"? What is the ComboBox for?

Comment: And/or screenshots to illustrate the probelm would also be most helpful.

Comment: I used microsoft Custom UI Editor to populate the combo box. Basically you have a list of options in the combo box and when you choose an option, some text is added in the slide. Look at my original post the XML file, where I illustrate one of the possible options

Comment: That's the `<item id="BU" label="BACK UP" />`?  So are you trying to somehow clear out the list of items? Or are you trying to set it simply to a default null-string/blank value?  Again, some screenshots and/or illustrations of the *desired results* and how they differ from the *actual results* would be most helpful.

Comment: My idea is to set it to blank/null after the selection, so it can be selected the same option again. Basically when I make a selection the value sticks in the combo box and the same value cannot be selected again

Comment: OK so I went through the trouble of creating this since I couldn't get you to provide any screenshots. Please refer to updated answer above...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57869/discussion-between-dan-stern-and-david-zemens).

Comment: @DanStern: Ribbon combo-boxes (dropdowns) are populated dynamically be declaring, and servicing, the callback methods **getItemCount(ctl As IRibbonControl, ByRef Count)** and **getItemLabel(ctl As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef Label)**.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens yes for `dropDown` controls, the `comboBox` list from OP is set in the XML. I've revised my answer to use dropdown as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub Sticker1(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, text As String)
'do stuff
Call MyRibbonV.InvalidateControl ("ddlItem")
End Sub
```

Notice the keyword "Call" added to the original code.

Comment: Nothing happens when using this approach. No error, and no invalidation taken place

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had used this in the ApplicationEvents class and this had worked for me.